# React-Native new Date() giving time in different timezones in different android mobiles.

Tags: javascript, android, time, react-native

I am trying to show time picker in iOS and android through React-Native. I set the time as `date={new Date()}`. It is working fine in iOS. Giving me the current time. It also works in certain android devices like OnePlus. But in Samsung, Xiome, I get the UTC time instead of my local system time. What is the issue here and how can I fix it.

Comment: Try to use `momentJS` and enforce `locale` on it?

Comment: I tried, getting the same result.